# How to close the emoji palette using the keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, emoji

I know that there is a keyboard shortcut that lets you open the emoji palette while you are typing, but I could not find any shortcut that lets you close the palette.

So right now, whenever I finish adding my emoji I manually close it by tapping on the top-left red X button. This is quite troublesome, so is it possible to close it via the keyboard shortcut?

I use Mojave on 2017 MacBook 12'.

Answer (score 2):

If your emoji window looks as on the screenshot below - it means that you might have accidentally switched it from the default popup mode into that half-broken "window" mode. I did it once as well, no idea how. You need to press the highlighted button and it's going to get back to the popup mode.

In the popup mode it disappears once you press the `esc` or select an emoji with the arrow keys and press `enter`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is somewhat awkward.

Even the Menu option doesn't toggle it on/off, only on.

If you simply double-click your emoji without doing anything else, it doesn't even bring the window to the front...

..so, the only real option is after you open it, click its header bar [while you're over there anyway to grab your emoji]
It will then respond to  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  the same as any other window.

<sup>Of course, if you forget, it will close the window you were working in  :\</sup>

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I've been doing, but I don't want to tap the emoji window and then send ⌘+w. Also, the emoji palette keeps in front of the other windows, so I must close it or move it somewhere, anyway. Very sickening behavior...